# PHP script returns no result

Tags: php, sql

I have a script where I try to get the `date` from my database.

The script needs to show: The date in the database is (date). Click here to continue. When I run the SQL query in phpMyAdmin, the SQL query returns the date. When I run it in my script I get no result.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "db";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = "set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL';";
 $sql = "SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date FROM table WHERE id='1'";
 $result = $conn->multi_query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "The date in the database is:";
   echo " " . $row['date'] . ". ";
   echo "Click here to continue.";
   }
  } else {
   echo "0";
  }
?>
```

When I run this script I get `0`. When I change `echo "0";` with `echo " " . $row['date'] . ". ";` I get a empty page.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: PHP's mysql adapter _all_ only process the first statement in the sql argument handed over. That has security reasons to prevent sql injection attacks. That means your `set` statement is executed, the `SELECT` statement is silently dropped.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to run this script with: `set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL';`?

Comment: Run it as two separate statements in sequence. The mysql connection has a state.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Em... you use `$conn->query($sql);` to execute a statement, right? You certainly can do that _twice_ in a sequence, can't you?

Comment: See my first post, I just edited. Now I have  2x `$sql =` and I changed `$result = $conn->query($sql);` to `$result = $conn->multi_query($sql);`. I still get "0" with this.

Comment: OK... Let's take a look at the `SELECT` statement itself... Are you sure you have a table called `table`? I somehow doubt that... Why not simply `SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') as \`date\``?

Comment: Ah, and obviously those two assignments to the same variable `$sql` do not make _any_ sense. The second string replaces the first one.

Comment: Yes, I called it table. I can run the SQL query in phpMyAdmin

Comment: You called a table "table"????? Anyway, the `WHERE` is simply not required here.

Comment: Do I need to add a `.` at the end of the last `$sql `? Like in the example in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Have a try with that if you insist on the WHERE clause: `SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date FROM \`table\` WHERE id='1'`, though as said: `SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date` should return exactly the same and be faster.

Comment: I called it table, Its just a 'test table'.

Comment: You can either concatenate those two strings, yes, or just stick with the previous notation you had. You need two separate strings (commands) if you use `$conn->query(...);` twice. If you use `$conn->multi_query();` you need both statements in a single string as you initially had it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had another edit that isn't approved...does this work?

Just splitting your queries/variables into 2 separate ones--only only worry that first value may not persist for you.

Like so:

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "db";

 // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }  

$sql = "set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL'";
$sql2 = "SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date FROM table WHERE            id='1'";
 $resultZ = $conn->query($sql);
 $result = $conn->query($sql2);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "The date in the database is:";
    echo " " . $row['date'] . ". ";
    echo "Click here to continue.";
   }
   } else {
    echo "0";
   }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using mysqli_query (which executes exactly ONE query) and thus your script is only ever getting to the set variable statement and ending at the semicolon.

Follow the advice below--the 2nd example shows using multi_query and setting the variable value just like you do in phpMyAdmin.

Try with:

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "db";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = "SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date FROM table WHERE id='1'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "The date in the database is:";
   echo " " . $row['date'] . ". ";
   echo "Click here to continue.";
   }
  } else {
   echo "0";
  }
?>
```

Or use [`multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php):

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "db";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = "set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL'; SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date FROM table WHERE id='1'";
 $result = $conn->multi_query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "The date in the database is:";
   echo " " . $row['date'] . ". ";
   echo "Click here to continue.";
   }
  } else {
   echo "0";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Its working, but I need `set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL';`

Comment: It is not working again when I use `$result = $conn->multi_query($sql);`

Comment: @Fernando. Multi query gives me the same result

Comment: @Fernando Rodriquez no problem, I am glad you helped him, because I am no longer at the computer and I couldn't update my answer. Also, please take my upvote

Answer (score 1):

You have formatted the sql script.. So instead of writing $row['date'] just put like this $row[0]

Hope this works for you..

Comment: FYI this would also work--but he is perfectly capable of calling the data columns by name rather than index.